# Installing SciPy on Mac OS Lion in Virtualenv

Tags: python, macos, installation, scipy

I am trying to install scipy in my vertualenv on mac.

Python using in virtualenv:

```
(Django)miki725mac:Django miki725$ python
Python 2.7.2 (default, Aug  3 2011, 00:58:00) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2335.15.00)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

I tries installing scipy by doing this which fails:

```
$ svn co http://svn.scipy.org/svn/scipy/trunk scipy
$ python setup.py build
$ python setup.py install
```

Then I tried:

```
$ pip install scipy
```

Also as per the suggestion I tried:

```
$ pip install -e git://github.com/scipy/scipy@effa6f68f8ada57b7986#egg=scipy-dev
```

**Logs**

Here are the complete logs for all the insallation steps: (they were too long for stackoverflow)

`python setup.py build`

http://www.diglo.com/download/3dfc7a1af18617d7ee49faa8bea3464703ea

`python setup.py install`

http://www.diglo.com/download/ab13985c76ad709b25464fa1254daa4b03ea

`pip install scipy`

http://www.diglo.com/download/9e808fe5b57b6b01a8265d4b01958da703ea (pastebin: http://paste.pocoo.org/show/454004/ )

`pip install -e git://github.com/scipy/scipy@effa6f68f8ada57b7986#egg=scipy-dev`

http://www.diglo.com/download/085f7bd08e7cb86823718b94641ecacd03ea

Please help. I am new at all this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please update your question and post the first few lines of errors instead of the last – these are the ones which actually contain the source of the error.

Comment: Err, sorry, that's a bit too high… I meant “the first few lines which contain compile errors”. Can you post the entire output?

Comment: its too long for stackoverflow. tonight I will put it somewhere else.

Comment: just uploaded the complete logs. Thank you

Comment: Hrm… I hate to say it, but that's not an error I've run into before. Sorry =\ (also, for your future reference: sites like http://paste.pocoo.org and http://pastebin.com are very useful when you want to send these sorts of errors around).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Up until August 2011 Scipy was broken on Mac OS X Lion.  Fixed in this commit: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/commit/effa6f68f8ada57b79864852b609ff06d2527306

It looks like this change has not yet been merged to SVN trunk.  Try github instead:

```
pip install -e git://github.com/scipy/scipy@effa6f68f8ada57b7986#egg=scipy-dev
```

That's worked for me on two installs of Lion.  However if it doesn't I've heard using GCC-4.0 (instead of the current default: GCC-4.2) also solves the issue (haven't verified it though):

> 1. Install macports
> 2. sudo port install gcc40
> 3. Create a symlink from gcc-4.0 to gcc
> 4. Recommended: after scipy is installed, change the symlink to point back to the xcode version of gcc-4.2

Steps 1 & 2 are only needed if you don't already have gcc-4.0.

Comment: did not work. how do you switch to GCC-4.0? And if I don't have it installed how do I install it

Comment: I tried. This is what I get:
`Error: Target org.macports.fetch returned: gcc40 does not build on Lion.`

Answer (score 9):

Personally, I found the easiest and reliable way to install scipy/numpy on Mac OS Lion was through the [scipy superpack shell-script on github](http://github.com/fonnesbeck/ScipySuperpack) . As Steve Jobs says - it just works. Nothing more to do.

**Steps to install scipy in a virtual env:**

- Download the [scipy superpack install script](https://github.com/fonnesbeck/ScipySuperpack/blob/master/install_superpack.sh)
- Open the install script and change *PYTHON=/usr/bin/python* to *PYTHON=`which python`*
- Activate virtual env, and inside your virtual env, run the install script
- Bingo! that's all you need to do

Comment: best to get the most recent superpack from here: https://github.com/fonnesbeck/ScipySuperpack

Comment: This appears to be the best way to do it with virtualenv. The install script did run homebrew, however, so it does install the non-python dependencies "system wide". I guess that's probably the right way to do it anyhow.

Comment: the link is broken :(

Comment: Thanks @vgoklani. I updated the answer to point to the right download pages now.

Answer (score 1):

What about going with the [official instructions](http://www.scipy.org/Installing_SciPy/Mac_OS_X)?

It seems you are using the default Python installation, which is not recommended...

Comment: I installed python from the official dmg. Where is it? it did not became the default one.

Comment: Lion ships with Python 2.7, which is sufficient. The criticism against the default Python in OS X was only valid for earlier versions of OS X, which shipped with a very dated Python 2.5. Those criticisms do not apply to OS X 10.7 (Lion).

Answer (score 1):

I ran into similar problem recently. After following the [office doc](http://www.scipy.org/Installing_SciPy/Mac_OS_X#head-9ec15aabd402675e5139a8c9c727e6a23513d56a) for installing `scipy` on Lion to no avail, I found the following resources that helped me fix it:

1. [Installing Python, virtualenv, NumPy, SciPy, matplotlib and IPython on Lion](http://www.thisisthegreenroom.com/2011/installing-python-numpy-scipy-matplotlib-and-ipython-on-lion/#numpy) (didn't really work for me but I imagine it works for most people)
2. [Install Python, NumPy, SciPy, and matplotlib on Mac OS X](http://penandpants.com/2012/02/24/install-python/)
    (this one works for me too, just remember to install `gfortran` with `homebrew` first, and then use `pip install scipy` to build and install `scipy`. Though I suspect it might not always work).
3. [Scipy Superpack](http://fonnesbeck.github.com/ScipySuperpack/) (this one is the easiest and fastest since it simply installs compiled binaries for Lion)